# Reference request: "Fernique-type" integrability condition on measures

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, reference-request

Let $(\mathcal{C}, \|\cdot\|)$ be a (non-locally compact) Banach space with Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$.

Given a probability measure $\mu : \mathcal{B}\rightarrow[0,1]$, I'm interested in regularity (''growth'') conditions on $\mu$ which guarantee that

$$\tag{1}\|\mu\|:=\int_{\mathcal{C}}\!\|x\|\,\mu(\mathrm{d}x) \, < \, \infty.$$

Clearly, probability measures with bounded support are of this form. Do you know of a reference where (Fernique-like) conditions of the form $(1)$ are studied in greater generality?

Comment: Well, you can always write $$||\mu|| = \int_0^\infty \mu(\{x: ||x||\ge R\}) dR.$$